# How do I go about not having to write auto 20 times for grid-template-columns

Tags: css, css-grid

Hey all not to sure where I should ask this question but basically Im working on Etch a Sketch and for my original 16x16 grid. I used display:grid; and grid-template-columns and wrote auto 16 times. This did the trick but Im guessing its not the way to go when you have a grid that 90x90 Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `repeat()` function:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(90, 1fr);
```

This can be used for `grid-template-rows` also.

References:

- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
/*Creates 90 columns, each 150px in width*/
grid-template-columns: repeat(90, 150px); 
/*Creates 90 rows, each 150px in height*/
grid-template-rows: repeat(90, 150px);
```